# function declaring object in array is undefined -- NO! its not!-?

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, undefined-function

heres my code:

```
function insertMonsters() {

var monsterPositions = [2,8,13,15,22];

for ( var i in monsterPositions ) {
    monsters[i] = createMonster("monster",monsterPositions[i],1);
    document.getElementById(monsters[i].currentPosition).innerHTML = monsters[i].displayText;
    }

}

function createMonster(name,startingPoint,level){
    this.displayText = "<span>" + name + "</span>";
    this.currentPosition = startingPoint;
    this.level = level;
    this.health = function(){ return 25 + ( this.level * 15 );};
    this.strength = function(){return ( this.level * 3 );};
}
```

and i get a error:

```
TypeError: createMonster(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

monsters[i] = createMonster("monster",monsterPositions[i],1);
```

and i kinda really got no clue whats wrong, [link here](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/adventure.html) help please.

Comment: @BrianMayer i do earlier on just didnt put my whole program here thanks though

Comment: Tip: Don't loop arrays with `for..in` but a regular `for` loop.

Comment: @php_nub_qq didnt quite catch that but im trying now...

Comment: @php_nub_qq ...still nothing got no clue whats going on

Comment: Disregard my comment. Still looking

Comment: @php_nub_qq answered already thanks though it was a missing `new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like its `monsters` thats undefined, not createMonster.  Make sure to initialize the `monsters` array and you should be ok.

You can change line 7 to

```
var monsters = [];
```

you're also missing a `new` statement when setting the monster,

you need

```
monsters[i] = new createMonster("monster",monsterPositions[i],1);
```

Comment: i do define it earlier, i just didnt include my entire code, anyway that wouldnt be an error, it would just give me a local variable when i want a global one.

Comment: Its not initialized in the code you link to.  Thats the error I see there.  When I load up the page, monsters is not defined and throws an error in Chrome's console log.

Comment: look at line 7 in the script

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight yep you declare it but don't initialize it.  You need to set it to an empty array or object before you try setting a property on it.  change line 7 to `var monsters = [];` and you should be fine

Comment: you're also missing a `new` statement.  createMonster doesn't return anything.  You need to use new to use it as a constructor, or you need to give it a return value

Comment: @ben336 but I don't understand, why would a `new` be required with a regular function like that?

Comment: @php_nub_qq because it creates a object its like writing `Object()` instead of `new Object()`

Comment: @php_nub_qq Javascript doesn't distinguish between constructors and "normal functions"  new can work with any function.  It just creates a new object and binds that object to the function (so that `this` in the function points to the new object).  Since the createMonster function is acting on this and doesn't return anything, I assumed it was meant to be used as a constructor with `new`

Comment: @ben336 It seemed weird to me how a regular function uses this and returns nothing, but now thanks to you I understand!